# Read data from .dat file as rows and columns, ignore comments with loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have a .plt file with 110 datasets each with 11 rows and 9 columns. The datasets are separated by 3 rows of comments each time. I want to read the file as rows and columns. Panda reads it as rows but doesn't recognize the columns. This may be because the first three lines of the file are comments. One starting with '#' and the other two with '$'. How do I make panda convert this to a csv type file?

I have tried read_csv, read_fwf and put delimiters and comments and skipped the first three rows but it still recognizes all the columns as 1 column with index 0.

Comment: Can you show an example of the file structure and of what you want the read data to look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up ignoring those lines by using

```
test = pd.read_table(filename, header=None)
    list_a = test.iloc[start:end]
```